# Python 3: Convert Tuple to Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

**Trying to Convert this:**

```
word_vomit = [(('best', 'cat', 'breed'), 3), (('dogs', 'wearing', 'hats'), 3), (('did', 'you', 'eat'), 2), (('cats', 'are', 'evil'), 1), (('i', 'hate', 'lists'), 1)]
```

**Into this:**

```
goal = {'best cat breed': '3','dogs wearing hats': '3','did you eat': '2','cats are evil': '1','i hate lists': '1'}
```

Thanks in advance for any and all comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a concise option using a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
word_vomit = [(('best', 'cat', 'breed'), 3), (('dogs', 'wearing', 'hats'), 3), (('did', 'you', 'eat'), 2), (('cats', 'are', 'evil'), 1), (('i', 'hate', 'lists'), 1)]
output = {' '.join(k): v for k, v in word_vomit}
print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'best cat breed': 3, 'dogs wearing hats': 3, 'did you eat': 2, 'cats are evil': 1, 'i hate lists': 1}
```

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest approach, is there any reason this wouldn't be preferable over using join() as Warl0ck has?

Comment: Dictionary comprehensions are an uncommon feature in other programming languages, so it may confuse people with only a casual understanding of Python.  TBH, this might be the first one I've written.  But yes, it saves space, and if you understand dictionary comprehensions, it's pretty clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approch that you can use,

```
word_vomit = [(('best', 'cat', 'breed'), 3), (('dogs', 'wearing', 'hats'), 3), (('did', 'you', 'eat'), 2), (('cats', 'are', 'evil'), 1), (('i', 'hate', 'lists'), 1)]
dict1={}
for i in word_vomit:
    str1=""
    str1=" ".join(i[0])
    dict1[str1]=str(i[1])
print(dict1)
```

output:

```
{'best cat breed': '3', 'dogs wearing hats': '3', 'did you eat': '2', 'cats are evil': '1', ' i hate lists': '1'}
```

hope this helps you!

Comment: The output here doesn't match the desired because of the leading space.  I suggest warl0ck's answer.  str.join is your best option for this kind of conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use `.join` method on string to convert tuple to string.

```
word_vomit = [(('best', 'cat', 'breed'), 3), (('dogs', 'wearing', 'hats'), 3), (('did', 'you', 'eat'), 2), (('cats', 'are', 'evil'), 1), (('i', 'hate', 'lists'), 1)]

out_dict = {}

for worditem in word_vomit:
  out_dict[" ".join(worditem[0])] = worditem[1]

print(out_dict)
```

Comment: This is really helpful as well, thanks. I notice this works well even if it's working with two words at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
word_vomit = [(('best', 'cat', 'breed'), 3), (('dogs', 'wearing', 'hats'), 3), (('did', 'you', 'eat'), 2), (('cats', 'are', 'evil'), 1), (('i', 'hate', 'lists'), 1)]

goal = {}
for key_tuple, value in word_vomit:

    key = " ".join(key_tuple)

    goal[key] = str(value)
```